# JQuery is not working in Wordpress Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I cannot enqueue JQuery from Functions.php. Following is my function.
Can anyone tell me what am I missing?
Thanks

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function bootstrap_framework_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap-css/bootstrap.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-framework-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20140924', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-framework-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ie10-viewport-bug-workaround', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js', array(), '20140115', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'offcanvas-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/offcanvas.js', array(), '20130119', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_framework_scripts' );
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is already pre-registered in the latest builds of WordPress; so you don't need to explicitly enqueue it.

However, the jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode to prevent compatibility problems with other JavaScript libraries that WordPress can link. Read more about what this means for you, [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).